# Cognos 10 - Assign logged User Name to a parameter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cognos-10

Hell Team,

How to assign the user name to a parameter using Java script so that that parameter can be used in calculations.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the Cognos username directly with the following macro:

```
#sq($account.personalInfo.userName)#
```

You can use this in expressions or display it on the report.